# Как реализовать в си шарп аналог командной строки?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Как реализовать в си шарп аналог командной строки? Тоесть чтобы, я хочу ввести команду в консоли, например copy, дальше вызывалась моя функция.
Спасибо

Comment: Вроде, PowerShell такое умеет.

Comment: Можно реализовать паттерн команда https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Создаёте консольное приложение и делаете обработчики команд. И при чём здесь asp.net?